# Ordering objects by an attribute of a generic attribute

Tags: java, generics, compare

Say that I have this class:

```
public class Bucket<T> {
        T filling;
}
```

and the filling attribute can be an instance of either one of these:

```
public class Oil{
    float volume;
}
```

or

```
public class Water{
    float volume;
}
```

In one part of my code, I have a list of Buckets:

```
LinkedList<Bucket> list;
```

Now, I want to order the elements of "list"(Bucket) by the attribute "volume".
But I can't compare `T.volume`. So, how do I do that?

Sorry in advance if my question is stupid, I'm still learning java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answer you assuming this is a theoritical question, I do not advise you to implement that but to find a better pattern to do what you want.

You want to sort a List of Bucket. To call Collections.sort() method, Bucket needs to implements Comparable (and so to define compareTo method).

You should define an interface implemented by your "filling" elements

```java
interface Element {
    float getVolume();
    void setVolume(float volume);
}
```

```java
class Oil implements Element {
    float volume;

    @Override
    public float getVolume() {
        return volume;
    }

    @Override
    public void setVolume(float volume) {
        this.volume = volume;
    }
}
```

```java
class Water implements Element {
    float volume;

    @Override
    public float getVolume() {
        return volume;
    }

    @Override
    public void setVolume(float volume) {
        this.volume = volume;
    }
}
```

Now you can define Bucket class:

```java
class Bucket implements Comparable<Bucket> {
    Element filling;

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Bucket o) {
        return Float.compare(filling.getVolume(), o.filling.getVolume());
    }
}
```

And this code:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Bucket> elems = new LinkedList<>();
    Bucket o = new Bucket();
    o.filling = new Oil();
    o.filling.setVolume(5);

    Bucket w = new Bucket();
    w.filling = new Water();
    w.filling.setVolume(12);

    elems.add(w);
    elems.add(o);
    Collections.sort(elems);
    for(Bucket b: elems) {
        System.out.println(b.filling.getVolume());
    }
}
```

Will print:

```
5.0
12.0
```

Shame on me I wrote the whole code, but it's easier to understand by reading this one than reading a bad explanation I could write.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was trying to come with a solution using "Collections.sort()" too, I should've specified it in my question. I did a similar thing here, and it worked.

Comment: If you want to keep Bucket generic, you could do `class Bucket<T extends Element> implements Comparable<Bucket<T>`. Then keep the member as `T filling` (the `extends` bit means "T is at least an `Element`"), and you should be good to go.